# How to Eliminate multiple versions in a file using shell comamnds

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file test.txt as

```
xyz[4.3],default, 
xyz[4.4],default, 
xyz[4.6],default, 
xyz[4.7],default, 
harry[1.0],default, 
molly[1.1],default, 
abc[1.0],rome, 
abc[1.1],rome, 
abc[1.2],rome, 
abc[1.4],rome, 
ghi[1.0],moon, 
ghi[1.1-Test],moon, 
def[2.1],default, 
def[2.2],default, 
def[3.9],default, 
def[4.1],default, 
def[4.2],default,
```

now i need to files in Test1.txt with only latest 3 versions of the  above services:(ex:latest in the sense in xyz service 4.4,4.6,4.7 are latest 3 versions and  4.3 is old)

Note: i want the version number as parameter(say the number of versions i need to filter as a variable)

```
    xyz[4.4],default, 
    xyz[4.6],default, 
    xyz[4.7],default, 
    harry[1.0],default, 
    molly[1.1],default,
    abc[1.1],rome, 
    abc[1.2],rome, 
    abc[1.4],rome, 
    ghi[1.0],moon, 
    ghi[1.1-Test],moon,
    def[3.9],default, 
    def[4.1],default, 
    def[4.2],default,
```

and test2.txt with rest of the old versions:

```
xyz[4.3],default,
abc[1.0],rome,
def[2.1],default, 
def[2.2],default,
```

i have tried something but couldnt worked:

if ( any( [ x(i)/=x(j), y(i)/=y(j), amp(i)/=amp(j) ] ) ) then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the desired output in reversed order.  Run tac on each output file if that is an issue.

```
tac input | awk '{out=a[$1]++>2?"test2.txt":"test1.txt"; print > out}' FS=[
```

The code is simple: split on the `[` so that `$1` is the text preceding the `[`.  Reverse the input (with `tac`) so that the first 3 occurrences of a particular prefix are the highest versions and are printed to `test1.txt`, while remaining occurrences go to `test2.txt` (this assumes that your initial input is correctly sorted as shown in your example.)

Comment: thanks for the help..i want the versions number as a variable..lets say if i want only 2 versions(occurances) or some times first 4(ocurances)

Comment: Then use a variable: eg `awk '{out=a[$1]++>lim?"test2.txt":"test1.txt"; print > out}' lim=5 FS=[` to get the top 5.